# Не могу в потоке QThread передать или считать данные по COM порту на PYQT 5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, serial, qthread

Необходимо считать и записать данные по COM порту в потоке. Не принимает данные по COM порту в потоке. Не понимаю как передать сигнал метода потока правильно. Программирую недавно, буду рад любому совету.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QIODevice, QByteArray
from PyQt5.QtSerialPort import QSerialPort, QSerialPortInfo

# Класс потока где обьявляется счетчик и приниматются или передаются данные по COM порту
class MyThread(QtCore.QThread):
    #mysignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    mysignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QByteArray, name="My_Signal")
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self, parent)
        self.serport = QSerialPort()
        self.serport.setBaudRate(9600)
        self.serport.setPortName("COM3")
        self.serport.setDataBits(8)
        self.serport.setParity(0)
        self.serport.setStopBits(1)
        print(self.serport.open(QIODevice.ReadWrite))
        print(self.serport.isReadable())
        self.running = False
        self.count = 0

# функция с телом потока
    def run(self):
        self.running = True
        while self.running:
            self.count += 1
            #self.mysignal.emit("count = %s" % self.count)
            buf = self.serport.readLine(14)
            if buf:
                self.mysignal.emit(buf)
            print(buf)
            self.sleep(1)


# Класс главного окна со счетчиком и привзкой потока через сигнал класса MyThread
class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Нажми кнопку для запуска потока")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.btnStart = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Запустить поток")
        self.btnStop = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Остановить поток")
        self.vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.label)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.btnStart)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.btnStop)
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)
        self.mythread = MyThread()
        self.btnStart.clicked.connect(self.on_start)
        self.btnStop.clicked.connect(self.on_stop)
        self.mythread.mysignal.connect(self.on_change, QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection)

# Старт потока
    def on_start(self):
        if not self.mythread.isRunning():
            self.mythread.start()

# Останавливаем поток
    def on_stop(self):
        self.mythread.running = False

# Метод который получает данные через сигнал потока класса MyThread
    def on_change(self, s):
        self.label.setText(str(s))

# Метод который останавливает поток класса MyThread
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.hide()
        self.mythread.running = False
        self.mythread.wait(5000)
        event.accept()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle("Запуск и остановка потока")
    window.resize(300,100)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: помогает ли пост https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56847238/doesnt-update-serial-data-using-button-click/56848503#56848503  решить вашу задачу? Если нет, то объясните лучше, что и куда вы хотите передать и что у вас не получается.

Comment: У меня стоит задача получать данные с COM порта и отправлять в потоке. Большое приложение с базами данных, работа с интерфейсом и отображением принятых технологических параметров, требует многозадачности. Там увидел ответ как сделать без потока, но мне надо именно через потоки т.к. будет три COM порта с постоянным обменом информации по ним между 3мя контроллерами и одним ПК (АРМ). Надеюсь на понимание и совет опытных программистов. Как к такой серьезной задаче подойти правильно.

Comment: я не могу воспроизвести вашу задачу, потому что нет COM портов  
и не совсем понимаю процессы вашего приложени. 
Дополнительный поток нужен для выполнения тяжелых задач.
Какую тяжелую задачу вы собираетесь выполнять в методе `run` ?
Попробуйте описать лучше последовательность процессов, 
которые должны выполняться в вашем приложении.

Comment: while self.running: переделал бы на readyread

Comment: @S.Nick у него просто блокирующий `while True`, и возможно не один такой

Comment: @eri `while True` в методе `run` ничего не блокирует, потому что выполняется в другом потоке. Другое дело не безопасное использование `self.serport` в методе `run`.

Comment: arduino??????????

Comment: "Какую тяжелую задачу вы собираетесь выполнять" = while True - я это имел ввиду. оно блокирует новый поток

Comment: @eri  нет, не блокирует и процессор не грузит, т.к. имеет `self.sleep(1)`

Comment: да я не об этом.

Comment: @eri я когда спрашивал, меня не интересует `while True`, мня интересует, что будет внутри и насколько то что внутри является тяжелой задачей.

Comment: @JIoBuboJIT озвучьте что вы уже попробовали и ответьте на вопросы, которые возникли по ходу дебатов.

Comment: Есть устройство VT100 (текстовый компьютерный терминал производства DEC) оно постоянно отображает информацию которую получает по COM порту с контроллера турбины (1986 года производства). Необходимо заменить его на ПК. Протокол передачи свой. Данные всегда идут в потоке (их довольно много 480-2000 байт) и таких 3 контроллера. При команде /HA встает и есть возможность управления выходами контроллера.

Comment: Т.е. нужно уметь записывать данные в COM порт и Читать данные с COM порта в ПОТОКЕ и так с трех COM портов. Попутно ведется отображение значение, сигнализаций и ведение баз данных  в реальном времени (все реализовано кроме работы с COM портами в потоке).

Answer (score 1):

Создавайте объект серийного порта в методе `run`, чтобы он работал в рабочем окружении (адресном пространстве) потока.

Общая схема такая:

```
class MyThread(QThread):  

    # булевский флаг активности/завершения работы потока
    _quit = False

    def run(self):
        serial = QSerialPort()
        # необходимые настройки идут либо тут, либо в цикле, ниже,
        # если вы будете  их менять в процессе работы потока и серийного порта.
        # В таком случае их надо постоянно проверять и пересоздавать порт, при необходимости

        # Проверяем флаг выхода/завершения работы потока
        while not self._quit:            
            if not serial.open(QIODevice.ReadWrite):
                print('Не могу открыть порт. Ошибка - 'serial.error())
                return

            # Передача данных
            if <есть данные на передачу>:
                # Следующие пара функций вызываются вместе последовательно
                # передаем данные в com-порт
                serial.write(requestData)
                # ожидаем пока все данные будут переданы
                serial.waitForBytesWritten(<Время для передачи данных>)

            # Получение данных
            # currentWaitTimeout - время ожидания, в течении 
            # которого данных должны прийти, иначе вернется False и мы пойдем дальше
            if serial.waitForReadyRead(currentWaitTimeout):
                # Считываем то, что пришло
                QByteArray responseData = serial.readAll()

    # Останавливаем поток
    def stop(self):
        self._quit = True
```

Comment: @eri почему так грубо? разве не надо локировать булен - он же читается в run и параллельно может изменииться в stop другим потоком?

Comment: @eri я бы попробовал предложение Alexandera !

Comment: поток залочен на serial.waitForReadyRead( 99,99% времени . Запись булева атомарна - не нужен там лок

Comment: @eri хорошо, я думал, что в Python так же как в С++ в данном случае. Привычка. Подправлю )

Comment: в с++ запись булевой переменной не атомарна?

Comment: @eri В C++ все зависит от платформы на которой все собирается и запускается. У меня был проект в котором пока я не начал использовать std::atomic<bool> stop_ приложение крашилось

Comment: @eri вот в качестве примера https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16111663/do-i-have-to-use-atomicbool-for-exit-bool-variable

Comment: по крайней мере в питоне есть gil =) одновременно выполняется только один тред.

Comment: @eri это хорошо, но я как старый пес, битый прежним хозяином, все время вздрагиваю при виде знакомой палки ))

Comment: напишите лучше кто-нибудь ответ на слотах: сигнал readyRead, и мув ту тред - раз уж хочется новый тред

Answer (score 1):

В Qt уже есть основной цикл и слот что в порту появились данные.

```
class MyThreadedPort(QtCore.QObject):
    #mysignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    mysignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QByteArray, name="My_Signal")
    def __init__(self, port="COM3", parent=None):
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self) # отдельный тред делается без parent
        self.thread = QtCore.QThread()

        self.moveToThread(self.thread) # уводим слоты в тред

        self.serport = QSerialPort()
        self.serport.setBaudRate(9600)
        self.serport.setPortName(port)
        self.serport.setDataBits(8)
        self.serport.setParity(0)
        self.serport.setStopBits(1)

        self.thread.moveToThread(self.thread) # уводим порт в свой поток
        
        print(self.serport.open(QIODevice.ReadWrite))
        print(self.serport.isReadable())
        self.serport.readyRead.connect(self.readyread)
        self.running = False
        self.count = 0

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def stop(self):
        self.running = False # флаг ставится в треде - мутекс не нужен (QueuedConnection)
        self.serport.close() # достаточно закрыть порт
        
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def readyread(self):
        while self.running and self.serial.bytesAvailable() >= 14:
            self.count += 1
            buf = self.serport.readLine(14)
            self.mysignal.emit(buf)
            
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot('QByteArray')
    def write(self, data):
        self.serport.write(data)
        self.serport.flush()
```

Comment: `self.serport.moveToThread(self) # уводим слоты в тред` - вероятно, опечатка

Comment: да, опечаточка. писал кусок тут в браузере на основе вопроса. не проверял

Comment: Пытаюсь понять реализацию вашего кода и выходят ошибки конечно же. Еще не использовал декораторы и не знаю что это (вот и повод). А можно одновременно считывать информацию с 3х COM портов  использую MyThreadedPort? Может нужно делать на каждый COM порт свой поток? Информация о турбине приходит постоянно и без запроса. Выше в комментариях писал общий принцип.

Comment: И все равно, в той строке что-то странное. Поток уводим в .. куда?

Comment: дада...) не в ту сторону повел..)

Comment: @JIoBuboJIT у меня нет под рукой сейчас ком портов чтоб полностью воспроизводимый пример написать. можно одновременно считывать 3 порта в одном треде, можно каждому сделать по треду - тут разницы не будет. информация будет читаться постоянно без запроса. декораторы для того чтоб qt обозначить функцию слотом. если её запускать через сигнал - она выполнится в треде объекта.

Comment: Спасибо за один из вариантов подхода. Пришлось искать информацию на других ресурсах т.к. тут не все ясно было. Сейчас пытаюсь данные по COM порту записать или получить т.к. почему то их не видит тестовый ноутбук. Все проверил через программу COMport tool kit и все данные приходят и уходят. Ошибок нет. Задам еще новый вопрос и потом тут все распишу и исправлю для людей будет интересно кому надо (таким как я).